# At Android Studio, can I delete themes.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

I'm making simple chat app right now with code at other guy's blog.
At this blog, this guy is using style.xml. But I installed latest Android studio, so I have only `themes.xml`. And I have no idea how to use themes.xml.
Is there any problem if I delete `themes.xml` and make new `style.xml`?

[image: error]

I made new `styles.xml` and got colorprimary error. So this error come from 'MaterialComponents' not from `styles.xml` or `themes.xml` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename is not relevant.
You can create a file in `res/values/custom_styles.xml` and put there the **`<style>`** resources

Currently the newer templates provided by AndroidStudio make use of `themes.xml` instead of `styles.xml`. Just use them in the same way.

In `res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

In `res/values/colors.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#......</color>
    <!-- ....  ->
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if both themes.xml and styles.xml exist, so I think you can add styles.xml without deleting themes.xml.
themes.xml and styles.xml have similar elements but different purposes. Please see below.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#versus